# why fread sometimes encounters "Bad file descriptor"?

Tags: c, file, stream, fread

I am read from a file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("sorted_hits", "r+");

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        int item_read;
        int *buffer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        item_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        if(item_read == 0) {
            printf("at file %ld\n", ftell(fp));
            perror("read error:");
        }
    }
}
```

This file is big and I got the "Bad file descriptor" error sometimes. "ftell" indicates that the file position stopped when error occurred.

I don't know why it is "sometimes", is that normal? does the problem lie in my code or in my hard disk? How to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`perror` prints whatever is in `errno` as a descriptive string.  `errno` gets set to an error code whenever a system call has an error return.  But, if a system call DOESN'T fail, `errno` doesn't get modified and will continue to contain whatever it contained before.  Now if `fread` returns 0, that means that either there was an error OR you reached the end of the file.  In the latter case, `errno` is not set and might contain any random garbage from before.

So in this case, the "Bad file descriptor" message you're getting probably just means there hasn't been an error at all.  You should be checking `ferror(fp)` to see if an error has occurred.

Comment: In addition to that, the `printf("at file %ld\n", ftell(fp));`  line before the call to `perror("")` could set errno , so it might not be the errno of the fread that is printed.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be mixing text and binary modes when reading the file.

Normally when you use `fread` you read from a binary file i.e. `fread` reads a number of bytes matching the buffer size but you seem to be opening the file in text mode (r+). `ftell` doesn't work reliably on files opened in text mode because newlines are treated differently than other characters.

Open the file in binary mode (untranslated) instead:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("sorted_hits", "rb+");
```

Comment: This was actually my problem! My file was opened with mode "r" and nealry all went file, but when some special characters (I cannot find out which exactly) are in the file the read command fails with error "bad file descriptor". So thanks for the hint, it fixes my problem!

Comment: @MeisterSchnitzel glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

If that's really what your loop looks like, my guess would be that you're probably getting a more or less spurious error because your process is just running out of memory because your loop is leaking it so badly (calling `malloc` every iteration of your loop, but no matching call to `free` anywhere).

It's also possible (but a lot less likely) that you're running into a little problem from your (common but nearly always incorrect) use of `while (!feof(fp))`.

Your all to `printf` also gives undefined behavior because you've mismatched the conversion and the type (though on many current systems it's irrelevant because long and int are the same size).

Fixing those may or may not remove the problem you've observed, but at least if you still see it, you'll have narrowed down the possibilities of what may be causing the problem.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("sorted_hits", "r+");

    int buffer;

    while(0 != fread(&buffer, sizeof(int), 1, fp))
        ; // read file but ignore contents.

    if (ferror(fp)) {
        printf("At file: %ld\n", ftell(fp));
        perror("read error: ");
    }
}
```